# How to iterate a list reversely and stop with a condition with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a list with some items for example

```
["a", "b", "c", ..., "x", "y", "z"]
```

I would like to iterate it but from the end to beggining and push those items into a new variable, and stop when it has length == 3.

For that simple example I would like to have as result within my new var:

```
["z", "y", "x"]
```

I'm thinking of `.reverse()` my array and then iterate it with `.each` and push my items, but I believe there is a better way to do that with lodash, that I'm not finding.

Maybe I'm not knowing how to search.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MaxZoom no lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the function "_.takeRightWhile" from lodash like the code below:

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"];
var reverseArray = [];
_.takeRightWhile(arr, function(item){
    reverseArray.push(item)
    return reverseArray.length < 3
});

console.log(reverseArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In plain Javascript you could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a negative count for getting a new array from the end and use [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) for a reversed array.

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"],
    result = array.slice(-3).reverse();
    
console.log(result);
```

For processing items, you could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"],
    result = array.slice(-3).reduceRight((r, a) => r.concat(a), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The "vanilla" way )

Comment: it's a nice way, but my need is to iterate, because I need to do things with each element, your way don't iterate, so I would need to call another iterate function.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that iterates the original array:

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"], res=[], count=3;
if (count <= arr.length)
  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) res.push(arr[arr.length-1-i]);

console.log(res);
```